# CakePHP: $this->Auth->allow() and $this->Auth->allowedActions() - when do I use them?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AuthComponent: Difference between allowedActions and allow()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705310/authcomponent-difference-between-allowedactions-and-allow)

What is the difference between using the method

```
$this->Auth->allow()
```

and setting the variable

```
$this->Auth->allowedActions ?
```

I can't find any information about setting the allowedActions array where I expected to find it (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1251/Setting-Auth-Component-Variables) - but it exists in the API at http://api13.cakephp.org/class/auth-component.

Can someone please explain which different circumstances I should use them?

Comment: Here's a link to a similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705310/authcomponent-difference-between-allowedactions-and-allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [AuthComponent: Difference between allowedActions and allow()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705310/authcomponent-difference-between-allowedactions-and-allow)